# Mongoose: Find a document by field and field inside an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a questionnaire that has the following schema:

```
var questionnaireSchema = new Schema({
    user_id : String,
    start_date : Date,
    end_date : Date,
    questions : [{
        question_id : {type: Number},
        answer_id : {type: Number},
        answer_string : String
    }]
});
```

I need to be and to find an answer set by the user_id and then see if that user has answered that question already.

I have the following query:

```
Questionnaire.findOne({'user_id': req.body.uid}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (user) {

            Questionnaire.findOne({
                'uid': req.body.uid,
                'questions.question_id': req.body.question_id

            }, function (err, question) {
                if (question) {
                    console.log('Found a question - updating');
                } else {
                    console.log('No question found - adding');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The query finds the user, however, when I try to find the user and question.answer_id together, the query never find anything.

I'm not sure how to write this query or where to look.

Thank you

Comment: What's that `Assesment` model? Shouldn't the query be on `Questionnaire` too, and reduced the code to a single query?

Comment: Sorry, i've updated it. It needs to have both queries. Its the second query that I'm having trouble with?

Comment: Where is `uid` key in the `Questionnaire` model?

Comment: @chridam That was exactly my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`question_id` is a Number in your schema. What's the type of `req.body.question_id`?
Depending on the request's `content-type`, it could be a string, hence the 2nd query cannot match anything.